# Is there a way to create an array of objects using php and create an json file from it

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I'm trying to create an array of objects with data coming from multiple tables, lets say there is table that hold patient data and there is table that hold diagnosis, and medicine for every patient that admitted to clinic, and i need to create an array of objects with the following output.
[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPjh5.png)

And i have to write the following code

```
 <?php
    // Db configs.
    define('HOST', 'localhost');
   define('PORT', 3306);

    define('DATABASE', 'new_nhif');
    define('USERNAME', 'root');
    define('PASSWORD', '');

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 

$mysqliDriver = new mysqli_driver();
$mysqliDriver->report_mode = (MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$connection = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE, PORT);

$sql = sprintf(
        'SELECT 
                nh.MembershipNo,
                nh.FullName,
                nh.id as nhid,
                lb.labrequest,
                fd.diagnosis,
                fd.DiseaseCode,
                fd.CreatedBy as fdcrb,
                dz.name

            FROM nhif_data AS nh 
            LEFT JOIN laboratory AS lb ON lb.re_id = nh.id 
            LEFT JOIN foliodisease AS fd ON fd.re_id = nh.id
            LEFT JOIN dawa_zilizotoka AS dz ON dz.re_id = nh.id
            WHERE  lb.re_id = nh.id
            AND  fd.re_id = nh.id
            AND  dz.re_id = nh.id
            -- GROUP BY nh.MembershipNo
           '
);

$obj = new stdClass;


$result = $connection->query($sql);

$vipimo = array();
$dawa = array();
$all = array();


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            
            // print_r(json_encode(['entities'=> $row],JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));

             $obj->MembershipNo = $row['MembershipNo'];
             $obj->FullName = $row['FullName'];

             $id = $row['nhid'];
            

             $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM foliodisease WHERE re_id ='$id'";
        
             $result1 = $connection->query($sql2);
            

             if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {

                while($row2 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
                       
                        $vipimo['diagnosis']= $row2['diagnosis'];
                        $vipimo['DiseaseCode']= $row2['DiseaseCode'];

                        $obj->FolioDiseases[] =  $vipimo;
                }
            
             }


             $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM dawa_zilizotoka WHERE re_id = $id";
        
             $result3 = $connection->query($sql3);
            

             if ($result3->num_rows > 0) {

                while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
                       
                        $dawa['name']= $row3['name'];

                        $obj->FolioItems[] =  $dawa;
                }
            
             }


             $all[] = $obj;

             }

             print_r(json_encode(['entities'=> $all], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));


     
     }
?>
```

And it give out the following output

```
{
  "entities": [
    {
      "MembershipNo": "602124502",
      "FullName": "Omari M Simba",
      "FolioDiseases": [
        {
          "diagnosis": "typhoid",
          "DiseaseCode": "J54"
        },
        {
          "diagnosis": "homa",
          "DiseaseCode": "L54"
        },
        {
          "diagnosis": "malaria",
          "DiseaseCode": "b54"
        }
      ],
      "FolioItems": [
        {
          "name": " Fluticasone furoate\t"
        },
        {
          "name": " Acyclovir  Eye ointment\t"
        },
        {
          "name": " Acyclovir\t"
        },
        {
          "name": " Acyclovir\t"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "MembershipNo": "602124502",
      "FullName": "Omari M Simba",
      "FolioDiseases": [
        {
          "diagnosis": "typhoid",
          "DiseaseCode": "J54"
        },
        {
          "diagnosis": "homa",
          "DiseaseCode": "L54"
        },
        {
          "diagnosis": "malaria",
          "DiseaseCode": "b54"
        }
      ],
      "FolioItems": [
        {
          "name": " Fluticasone furoate\t"
        },
        {
          "name": " Acyclovir  Eye ointment\t"
        },
        {
          "name": " Acyclovir\t"
        },
        {
          "name": " Acyclovir\t"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My tables are

nhif_data  ----
[nhif_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsHiM.png) ,

laboratory ----
[laboratory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbjrh.png),

foliodisease ---
[foliodisease](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgpX5.png) ,

dawa_zilizotoka ----
[dawa_zilizotoka](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGSGW.png)

Comment: Probably a reference issue. You're using the same object you created at the start, so any modifications made to it are reflected in your array. Move the object creation inside the `while` loop (at the beginning) so that a new instance is created in each iteration.

Comment: Why `sprintf()` if you aren't using any placeholders? That is an entirely useless call.  Iterated queries are a no-no.

Comment: Yeah true its works now i move the object creation inside a while loop and it works

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create an object array for the desired output, 'json_encode()' basically objectifies anything, meaning, no matter what you store with 'json_encode()' function, 'json_decode()' will always return you an object/array of objects, and so on.

All you need to fetch the records off the database, make child nesting as required, append the record to an array, and just 'json_encode()'; with 'json_decode()', you will end up with an array of objects.

```
$JSONItem = []; // Initialize the array

while($Record = $Query->fetch_assoc()){ // Iterate through main recordset
    ...subsequent child query   
    // Iterate though child recordset
    while($ChildRecord = $ChildQuery->fetch_assoc())$Record["Child"][] = $ChildRecord; // Append child node to main record
    $JSONItem[] = $Record; // Append record for JSON conversion
}

var_dump(json_decode(json_encode($JSONItem))); // This should return an array of ojects
```

Following should allow a better understanding of the mechanism;

```
var_dump(json_decode(json_encode([
    ["ID" => 1, "Name" => "Apple", "Source" => ["Name" => "Amazon", "URL" => "http://Amazon.Com", ], ], 
    ["ID" => 2, "Name" => "Banana", "Source" => ["Name" => "eBay", "URL" => "http://eBay.Com", ], ], 
    ["ID" => 3, "Name" => "Carrot", "Source" => ["Name" => "GearBest", "URL" => "http://GearBest.Com", ], ], 
])));
```

Or, with newer PHP version, I hope you can simply prepare/construct the array and objectify it with something like;

```
$JSON = (object) $JSONItem;
```